# Read numbers line by line from file and add on linked list

Tags: c, list, file-io, linked-list, readfile

For example i have two lines of numbers like below

12,4,11,16,3,20,9,19,17,15

20,3,10,12,18,2,5,14,15,16

I want read these numbers from a .txt file line by line and each line should be separate singly linked list.Shall I create 10 different variable for each line to store this numbers? I tried this but i could not any operand these numbers in this way.

Is this a correct way?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

struct list
{
  int data;
  struct list * next;
}list2;

struct list *head=NULL;


typedef struct list list;

void display();



int main() {

  list * node1 = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
  list * node2 = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
  list * node3 = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
  list * node4 = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
  list * node5 = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
  list * node6 = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
  list * node7 = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
  list * node8 = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
  list * node9 = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
  list * node10 = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));

  FILE *dosya = fopen("data.txt","r");
  int filenum;



  fscanf(dosya,"%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",&node1->data,&node2->data,&node3->data,&node4->data,&node5->data,&node6->data,&node7->data,&node8->data,&node9->data,&node10->data);
  
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let me answer your question "Is this a correct way?" with another question: Does your program *work?* If it doesn't, then you can answer your own question I think. I suggest you take a step back, and separate the assignment into smaller and simpler sub-assignments, which you then divide further until nothing can be divided any more. Then work on and implement *one* such little sub-assignment, build and test it. Only when it works you continue with the next little sub-assignment. And so on until your full assignment is implemented and working.

Comment: what do you expect to get doing  `fscanf(dosya,"%d",&filenum);` ? In your question the file seems to start by a line of 10 values separated by comma. Out of that you want to read several lines, so you need a loop, and to allocate a cell for each number and make the corresponding list for each line, and need to save the first cell of each line if you want to save all and not loose then reading next line => your global variable *head* is not the solution because can save only list for one line. To use 10 vars is not mandatory, out of the fact the arrays exist, all depends on the way you use

Comment: @bruno  My mistake.This line was about a another problem from .txt file.I want read every line and make some operations and print.After that,i will begin to the read next line numbers.

Comment: as proposed by @Someprogrammerdude you can do step by step if you cannot do all directly immediately, for instance forget the lists first and read the values of each lines and print them to check. Then introduce the lists etc

Answer (score 2):

Why are you hardcoding the 10? Let's just not do that.

```
struct list *read_list(const char *filename)
{
    errno = 0;
    struct list *head;
    FILE *dosya = fopen("data.txt","r");
    if (!dosya) return NULL;
    head = malloc(sizeof(*head));
    if (fscanf(dosya, "%d", &head->data) < 1) {
        fclose(dosya);
        free(head);
        return NULL;
    }
    for(struct list **ptr = &head->next;;ptr = &ptr[0]->next) {
         *ptr = malloc(sizeof(**ptr));
         if (!*ptr) {
             fclose(dosya);
             return head;
         }
         if (fscanf(dosya, ",%d", &ptr[0]->data) < 1) {
             fclose(dosya);
             free(*ptr);
             *ptr = NULL;
             return head;
         }
    }
}
```

Whew. Let's break this down. The function opens the file, initializes a linked list, and reads the first element into the head of the linked list. That's the easy part.

Then it runs a loop that allocates another node onto the end of the linked list and reads the comma into nothing and the next integer into the new node. If there's no more integers it gets rid of the node it just added and returns the result.

The list is returned if at least one integer was found in the file. Check `errno` to tell if a part read happened.